# A Driver Buffer Causes a 80 ms Delay When Using the USB WiFi Adapter, ALFA AWUS 036ACH

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, drivers, buffer, delay

I have a question about how to reduce delay for packets sent using a USB WiFi adapter, ALFA AWUS 036ACH.

I installed this driver (rtl8812au, version 5.2.20) for my USB WiFi adapter, ALFA AWUS 036ACH which uses chipset rtl8812au. I installed the driver for Ubuntu 16.04. The kernel version is 4.15.0. With the driver, the USB adapter can send and receive packets. However, the driver causes a 80 ms delay for packets sent. After I do a calculation, I think there is a buffer of about 200k bytes in the driver. But I didn’t find it. Do anyone have any idea about the buffer causing the 80 ms delay? Where is the buffer? How can reduce the size of the buffer. Thanks.

Comment: *"A Driver Buffer Causes a 80 ms Delay ..."* -- How did you derive this delay number?  How do you know that a buffer *"causes"* a delay?  Since this is a USB device there will be many buffers involved, yet you insist that there is just one buffer that is the root cause of a *"delay"*.

Comment: The delay is measured in this way. Record time at which a packet is inserted to the send socket buffer in a sender and time at which the packet is received by a receiver. Time difference (delay) is 80 ms. I know this delay is caused by a buffer because the delay is keeping increasing from about 0.5 ms to 80 ms and then stop at 80 ms when sending packets. Based on this observation, there should be a buffer between the sender and receiver. You are right, there are many buffers involved. There may not be just one buffer causing the delay. However, I need to limit the delay to a minimal number.

Comment: Your *"delay"* time seems to actually be a ***transmit+receive*** time, because it includes the time to send the message packet.  It also requires synchronized clocks.  *"I know this delay is caused by a buffer because ..."* -- IMO what you *"know"* is wrong.  Your crude scheme to measure *"delay"* is heavily subject to the variations of userspace scheduling (on ***both*** sides of the link).